# What might cause an ArgumentException (Given combination of Class, Part, and State is not defined by the current visual style)?

Tags: .net, exception, c++-cli

I have a C++/CLI .net application and I encountered a peculiar exception the other day (see below). I'm running on Windows XP Embedded if that makes a difference. What might cause this as it doesn't directly relate to any of my own code?

> ```
> Exception:
>     Given combination of Class, Part, and State is not defined by 
>     the current visual style.
> Exception type:
>     System.ArgumentException
> Source:
>     System.Windows.Forms
> Stack trace:
>     at System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleRenderer..ctor(
>         String className, Int32 part, Int32 state)
>     at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonRenderer.InitializeRenderer(Int32 state)
>     at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonRenderer.IsBackgroundPartiallyTransparent(
>         PushButtonState state)
>     at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonInternal.ButtonStandardAdapter.
>         PaintThemedButtonBackground(PaintEventArgs e, Rectangle bounds, 
>         Boolean up)
>     at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonInternal.ButtonStandardAdapter.
>         PaintWorker(PaintEventArgs e, Boolean up, CheckState state)
>     at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonInternal.ButtonStandardAdapter.
>         PaintUp(PaintEventArgs e, CheckState state)
>     at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonInternal.ButtonBaseAdapter.Paint(
>         PaintEventArgs pevent)
>     at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(
>         PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer, Boolean disposeEventArgs)
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>     at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(
>         Message& m)
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(
>         Message& m)
>     at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, 
>         Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>
>     Installed .net Versions:
>         v2.0.50727
> ```

Comment: I would argue that the statement "it doesn't relate directly to your code" isn't *wholly* accurate, since it's not *anyone else's* code that the exception is being thrown in.  That said, your example is a bit incomplete.  Is there anything specific that you are trying to do?  How about a small sample case which exhibits the same behavior?  It looks like when you are trying to create a `Form` of some kind; why not show the code for that?

Comment: @Casper: Perhaps "doesn't obviously trace back to a section of my code" would be a more accurate statement then? The code in question was runs on an embedded device for days at a time, but when I came back to it I found the exception above waiting for me. I can't really offer any more in terms of steps to reproduce; I just thought I'd stick it on here on the off chance that someone else might have seen something similar on their travels and gotten to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes straight out of Windows, the IsThemePartDefined() API function.  What's significant about this function is that it doesn't have any way to report an error, it can only return TRUE or FALSE.  A possible failure mode here is that it may run into some kind of internal error and can only reasonably return FALSE.  That's a kaboom in Winforms.

These kind of 'runs for days, then crashes' kind of errors do have an almost universal reason.  The process has exhausted one of the Windows resources quotas.  Pretty typical when your app is leaking handles.  The first order diagnostic for this is looking at the resources used by your app from the Taskmgr.exe Processes tab.  View + Select Columns and tick Handles, USER objects and GDI objects.

Comment: Right on the money as always Hans; it turned out to be a third party driver leaking ~20 handles per second. A quick check on their website revealed they'd released a driver update which fixes it.